# Convergence/Divergence of Sum

Tags: convergence-divergence

How can I check if the following sum converges/diverges? I don't believe the comparison test will give me the result in this specific case. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin (\frac{k^{2}+1}{k}\pi )$

Comment: It converges and I would like to know how to test it

Comment: @HelloWorld : I think that Wolfram evidence does not suggest it diverges.

Comment: It's an alternating series, so use the corresponding test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sin (\frac{k^{2}+1}{k}\pi)=\sin (k+\frac{1}{k})\pi=\cos k\pi \sin\frac{\pi}{k}=(-1)^k\sin\frac{\pi}{k}$ 
Now use alternating series test.